# AngularJS: ng-show for highest value of $index in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a input form for email address and address.

User can add upto 3 emails and address-lines dynamically by clicking `+` sign on the right of the input field.

When I `ng-repeat` input field `+` is also repeated for every input field.
How to show that + for only the last input field where the value of `$index` is maximum.[image: This is my actual form![][1]]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can instead use **`$last`** special property of `ng-repeat`. It is a boolean value property set for the last item (`item` here means **`child scope`** created by ng-repeat and not the value of that particular iteration) in the `ng-repeat`. Something like:

```
  ... ng-show="$last"
```

or

```
 ... ng-if="$last"
```

[See other special properties of ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> - **$index** - number  iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)
> - **$first** -  boolean true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.
> - **$middle** - boolean true if the repeated element is between the first and last in the iterator.
> - **$last** -   boolean true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.
> - **$even** -   boolean true if the iterator position $index is even (otherwise false).
> - **$odd** -    boolean true if the iterator position $index is odd (otherwise false).

Also note that if you plan to use `ng-show` (not `ng-if`) you could as well achieve it using css selectors pseudo-class like [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-child) , [:last-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/) etc based on the context and DOM structure.